# How to make a breakline in a textbox

Tags: html, css, textbox

Basically I want to something like below:

[image]

It is a textbox that has some predefined text. What is the best way to make it to appear like two rows and allow the texts within to have a breakline? As I've mentioned this is predefined text, I tried with `text="abcdef<br/>sss"` but it is showing `<br/>` instead of breaking a new line

Comment: Use RichTextbox or any editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use a `<textarea></textarea>` and `&#10;` for linebreaks

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
text="abcdef\nsss"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use textarea

Look at the sample in w3schools:-

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea